# What is the most accurate way of creating a raster from netcdf in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, projection, netcdf

I am processing netCDF data for multiple years. The netCDF is for air pollutant data, and the latitude and longitude are provided as **separate** variables, not as part of the original grid.

LINK TO DATE: [Sample Netcdf](https://utoronto-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/prp_patel_mail_utoronto_ca/EU2YgCr1kcRDhStKJ5MYoA4BUzvdvZuAofubfwOmH6sAEw?e=Vhvxpo)

These netCDF files provide Level 2 Nitrogen Dioxide data and they are downloaded from NASA Earthdata portal. The satellite is Sentinel-5P and the instrument is TROPOMI.

So when processing this data, you have to create variables for NO2, latitude and longitude. I am trying to create raster layers, and then save them as GeoTIFF files for my research.

The problem here is related to the fact that I don't know how best to create these rasters. The latitude and longitude is not equally spaced throughout the dataset, and I haven't figured out a way to accurately create these images. I created a model grid using the number of rows and columns provided by the netCDF files. In the list of variables this is called the scanline and ground_pixel, but when I plot it the cells in the final image don't look right.

This is how I upload the data:

```
## Open the netcdf
  ncname <- no2files$filename[m]
  ncfname <- paste(ncname, sep = "")
  nc <- nc_open(ncfname)
  
  ## Get the necessary variables. 
  no2tc <-ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column")
  lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/latitude")
  lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/longitude")
  qa <- ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/qa_value")
  
  fillvalue = ncatt_get(nc, "DETAILED_RESULTS/nitrogendioxide_total_column",
                  "_FillValue")
  mfactor <- ncatt_get(nc, "DETAILED_RESULTS/nitrogendioxide_total_column",
                  "multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_molecules_percm2")
  
  fillvalue_qa = ncatt_get(nc,"PRODUCT/qa_value",
                  "_FillValue")
  
  
  
  no2tc[no2tc == fillvalue$value] <- NA
  no2tc <- no2tc * mfactor$value
  
  qa[qa == fillvalue_qa$value] <- NA
  
  nc_close(nc)
  # rm(ncfname)
  
  no2vec <- as.vector(no2tc)
  latvec <- as.vector(lat)
  lonvec <- as.vector(lon)
  qavec <- as.vector(qa)
  
  dfsat <- data.frame(no2vec, lonvec, latvec)
  dfqa <- data.frame(qavec,lonvec,latvec)
  
  colnames(dfsat) <- c('z', 'x', 'y')
  colnames(dfqa) <- c('z', 'x', 'y')
  
  df <- rbind(df, dfsat)
  dfqa <- rbind(df,dfqa)
  rm(lat,lon,no2tc,qa,latvec,lonvec,no2vec,qavec)
```

This is how I currently create the raster:

```
  ## Create the raster. The ncol = 3245 and now = 450 are from the scanline and ground_pixel variables. 
  e <- extent(-180,180,-90,90)
  r <- raster(e, ncol = 3245, nrow = 450)
  
  xx <- rasterize(df[, 2:3], r, df[, 1], fun = mean)
  qa_raster <- rasterize(dfqa[, 2:3], r, df[, 1], fun = mean)
  
  crs(xx) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  crs(qa_raster) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  
  ## Crop and plot the raster
  ## change shapefile coordinate system 
  # border <- spTransform(ontario, crs(xx))
  aoi <- spTransform(ontario_buffer, crs(xx))
  
  ## Mask values with qa < 0.5 (this is the recommended value)
  
  xx[qa_raster < 0.5 & xx < 0] <- NA

  
  ## This is the final plot
  plot_tif <- crop(xx, extent(aoi))

  ### Use this if you want to view the plot. 
  mask_tif <- mask(plot_tif,aoi)
  # plot(mask_tif)
  # final <- plot(border,add=TRUE)
  
  ## Plot the raster 
  filename <- paste(i,".tif",sep="")
  writeRaster(mask_tif,filename = filename,"GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

The end results looks something like this:

[image: As you can see, the cells don't look right]

Then I tried another method I found online, but you have to set a resolution. I COULD do this, but I just want to plot the cells AS THEY ARE, without any modification.

```
ncfname <- "S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20200107T173517_20200107T191647_11582_01_010302_20200109T103930.nc"

nc <- ncdf4::nc_open(ncfname)

mfactor = ncdf4::ncatt_get(nc, "PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column","multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_molecules_percm2")
fillvalue = ncdf4::ncatt_get(nc, "PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column","_FillValue")
my_unit = ncdf4::ncatt_get(nc, "PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column","units")
my_product_name = ncdf4::ncatt_get(nc, "PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column", "long_name")

mfactor <- mfactor$value

fillvalue <- fillvalue$value

vals <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column")
lat <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/latitude")
lon <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(nc, "PRODUCT/longitude")
vals[vals == fillvalue] <- NA

vals_df = NULL

vals_df <- rbind(vals_df, data.frame(lat = as.vector(lat), lon = as.vector(lon), vals = as.vector(vals)))

pts <- vals_df

sp::coordinates(pts) <- ~lon + lat

my_projection <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

sp::proj4string(pts) <- sp::CRS(my_projection)

my_aoi <- ontario

crs_test <- raster::compareCRS(pts, my_aoi)

my_aoi <- sp::spTransform(my_aoi, CRS = as.character(raster::crs(pts)))


p <- methods::as(raster::extent(my_aoi), "SpatialPolygons")

sp::proj4string(p) <- sp::CRS(my_projection)

pts <- raster::crop(pts, p)

extent_distance_vertical <- geosphere::distm(c(raster::extent(pts)[1],                  raster::extent(pts)[3]), c(raster::extent(pts)[1], raster::extent(pts)[4]), 
                                               fun = geosphere::distHaversine)
  
vertical_mid_distance <- (raster::extent(pts)[4] - raster::extent(pts)[3])/2

lat_mid <- raster::extent(pts)[3] + vertical_mid_distance

horizontal_distance <- raster::extent(pts)[2] - raster::extent(pts)[1]
  

if (horizontal_distance > 180) {
  one_degree_horizontal_distance <- geosphere::distm(c(1,
                                                       lat_mid), c(2, lat_mid), fun = geosphere::distHaversine)
  extent_distance_horizontal <- one_degree_horizontal_distance *
    horizontal_distance
} else {
  extent_distance_horizontal <-
    geosphere::distm(c(raster::extent(pts)[1],
                       lat_mid),
                     c(raster::extent(pts)[2], lat_mid),
                     fun = geosphere::distHaversine)
}


my_res <- 20000
ncol_rast <- as.integer(extent_distance_horizontal/my_res)
nrow_rast <- as.integer(extent_distance_vertical/my_res)
print(paste0("Create raster file from points"))
rast <- raster::raster(nrows = nrow_rast, ncols = ncol_rast, 
                         crs = as.character(raster::crs(pts)), ext = raster::extent(pts), 
                         vals = NULL)
final <- raster::rasterize(pts, rast, pts$vals, fun = mean)

final <- raster::mask(final, my_aoi)

sp::plot(final)
```

[image]

How can I create these raster layers accurately? Thanks!

Comment: please provide access to an example file. If there is no direct URL, then please put it on a service like dropbox or google drive

Comment: Sure - question has been updated with link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example file

```
f <- "S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20200107T173517_20200107T191647_11582_01_010302_20200109T103930.nc"
```

You can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(f, paste0("/PRODUCT/", c("longitude", "latitude", "nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column")))
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 4172, 450, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : -0.5, 449.5, -0.5, 4171.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#sources     : longitude  
#              latitude  
#              nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column  
#varnames    : longitude (pixel center longitude) 
#              latitude (pixel center latitude) 
#              nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column (Tropospheric vertical column of nitrogen dioxide) 
#names       :    longitude,      latitude, nitrogendi~ric_column 
#unit        : degrees_east, degrees_north,               mol m-2 
#time        : 2020-01-07 

plot(r, nr=1)
```

[image]

The plot illustrates that the data are not organized as regular raster data (it they were, there would be a N-S gradient for latitude, and a E-W gradient for longitude). Also see `plot(r$longitude, r$latitude)`. You can treat them as points in stead:

```
dp <- as.data.frame(r)
p <- vect(dp, geom=c("longitude", "latitude"))
```

Plotting takes a while, as there are > 1.5 million points, so I take a sample

```
plot(p[sample(nrow(p), 10000)], "nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column")
```

If you want your data organized as a regular raster, you can use `rasterize`

```
x <- rast(res=1/6)
x <- rasterize(p, x, "nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column", fun=mean)
plot(x > 0)
```

[image]

And you can get Ontario like this

```
can <- vect(raster::getData("GADM", country="CAN", level=1))
ontario <- can[can$NAME_1=="Ontario", ]

x <- crop(x, ontario)
x <- mask(x, ontario)
plot(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So there's no way to plot them without having to set a resolution? Can you explain why that is necessary?

Comment: Think of the data as point data. You can plot them, but it is not easy. If you want to create a raster, you have to set a resolution. That would not concern me, especially for an atmospheric variable. I suppose in many cases there is a derived product in which this type of transformation has been done for you --- you just might not be aware of it.