# Extract data from NETCDF using shapefile

Tags: r, variables, polygon, raster, netcdf

I have downloaded ERA 5 data [Data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZq4b7dl_ZmJJVw7hCTe4D5TuyEhN4_d/view?usp=sharing) and trying to extract data using spatial polygons using following code-

```
library(raster)
south_asia  <- readOGR('E:/Bangladesh.shp')
library(ncdf4)

# read file 
library(RNetCDF)
nc <- nc_open("E:/ERA5_2000_03.nc")

# extract variable levels
lat <- ncvar_get (nc, "lat")
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
t <- ncvar_get(nc, "time")
pres <- ncvar_get(nc, "plev")
o3 <- ncvar_get(nc,'o3')
lonIdx <- which(lon > 59 & lon <99)  
latIdx <- which(lat >5 & lat < 39) 

# Name the array dimensions
dimnames(o3) <- list('lon' = lon, 
                     'lat' = lat,
                     'pres' = pres,
                     'time' = as.character(as.Date(t)))

extract3 <- o3[lonIdx,latIdx, , ]

# Monthly mean for each level of pres across the entire region of interest
p <- apply(extract3, c('pres', 'time'), mean)
```

Here, instead of using latIndex and lonIndex I want to extract data using a spatial polygon named "Bangladesh". How do I include this spatial polygon while extracting mean of the variable from the NetCDF dataset as given in link.

Thank you
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Very generally, take your .nc to raster brick [raster_brick from ncdf](https://pjbartlein.github.io/REarthSysSci/raster_intro.html), take your .shp to 'SpatialPolygons', give them both the same proj4string crs (which perhaps they have), and 'SpatialPolygons * raster_brick` clips to your study area, one hopes. Right now working on this warning:`In .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :
  "level" set to 1 (there are 5 levels)`...As I'm unfamiliar with the data, don't know the impact it will have or what more needs to be passed to `brick` to preserve levels.

Comment: thanks for your response but 'brick' and 'stack' doesnt work. It is a 4 dimensional dataset. Its difficult to extract using shapefiles. I can extract for a poin and rectangle/ square but not using polygons shapfiles

Comment: review `?raster::brick`, (as 4D is specifically mentioned) and fiddle around with `varname ='o3', lvar and level` in their various combinations and you'll see that they indeed work, one combination or 'lvar' and 'level' at a time per brick (that might then be further bricked). At least as far as I've worked out so far, so a SpatialPolygon will clip by multiplying `brick * SP`.  That's as far as I can take it. Others better versed will weigh in.

Comment: Tried again but failed. with error message "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘brick’ for signature ‘"ncdf4"’

Comment: nci<- brick("E:/ERA5_2000_03.nc", lvar = 3, level = 1, varname = 'o3')   . Just to make sure, the data has 17 pressure levels so should I use level (1-17) and for time dimension for all years, lvar =??? or should I leave 'lvar' blank ?

Comment: At this stage, perhaps we are dealing with a problem akin to [is underlying data actually point data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737552/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-of-creating-a-raster-from-netcdf-in-r), apply that approach and see how things develop. See @robert-hijmans comment on atmospheric variables under his answer. Looks promising anyway.

Comment: @Chris I did able to data using ```level``` only  as per your suggestion for 4D and cropped using spatial polygons. The link you provided is also helpful but ```level``` does the job. I ddnt understand what ```lvar``` does though. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've also been looking at approaching this using [tidync](https://ropensci.org/blog/2019/11/05/tidync/) that looks like it might simplify the approach, and you might want to take a look at that, as it is higher level while using the tools we've been discussing. I think also, you might want to expand your polygons to a 'regional' level inclusive of neighboring countries as o3, while 'over' Bangladesh, may source from neighbor, for your analysis.

Comment: thanks for advice..I did extended to South Asia now

Comment: So, it is perfectly valid to share your workflow to this point as an answer, and then accept your own answer, or wait for others to weigh in. I'm still working to understand `tidync` and how that gives access to `o3` through `time`, which I think has been the challenge rather than being stuck with one 'level at a time'.

Comment: Sure...in a while let me finish up the review process. I ll update my answer.